# (node:26972) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0'

Tags: node.js, ssl, dymo

I am using DymoJS (https://www.npmjs.com/package/dymojs) to print labels on my local machine and I get this error:

```
(node:26972) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification.
```

I tried installing ssl-root-cas (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssl-root-cas) but that does not help. I also tried changing NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED to '1' in the dymojs library but it does not work either.

Answer (score 14):

This warning appears once for each of the five JavaScript files that
get run, and can be safely ignored (in a development environment) and
does not affect the running of the tutorial.

Modify the lines to set the `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED` environment variable to `1`.

```
process.env["NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"] = 1;
```