# discord bot when connected is not responding according to my code

Tags: javascript, discord

I am building a Discord bot and I want my bot to respond pong after I type ping but it's not responding. My token is also correct. My code gets connected with bot but there is no response.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Partials } = require('discord.js');
const { Intents } = Discord;

const client = new Discord.Client({ 
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] 
})

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
})

client.on("message", msg => {
  if (msg.content === "ping") {
    msg.reply("pong");
  }
})

client.login("Its correct but I cant reveal")
```

Comment: Make sure that the bot has the necessary permissions to send messages in the Discord server where you are trying to use the "ping" command.
OR
Try using a different Discord server or channel to see if the problem persists. This can help you determine whether the issue is specific to a particular server or channel.

Comment: it has administrator rights

Comment: I already tries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need the `MessageContent` and `GuildMembers` intent to be enabled when you want to read the message contents in your `messageCreate` event.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Partials } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ 
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent
    ]
});

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
});

client.on("messageCreate", msg => {
  if (msg.content === "ping") {
    msg.reply("pong");
  }
});

client.login("Your token");
```

Also, double check on your [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers) if the intents are enabled.

`!` Not sure which version of Discord.js you are using, but the event for receiving message is `messageCreate`. The event `message` is deprecated and has been removed in the latest version already.

[image]

Comment: ok but after I added these intents then also same issue is coming

Comment: What are the error(s) you get?

Comment: Process exited with code 1
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe .\src\App.js
(node:23832) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Logged in as X_Mouse#3250!
ipt
Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: ipt is not defined
    at <anonymous> (undefined:1:1)

Comment: this error in vs code

Comment: Seems like your network is insecure, because with the same exact code I've posted in my answer, it should work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65021836/node26972-warning-setting-the-node-tls-reject-unauthorized-environment-varia

Comment: network is secure

Comment: can you send me complete correct code

Comment: @MuditDagar Complete code is in my answer, refresh the page to be sure. Which version of Discord are you using?

Comment: yes refreshed . I am on the latest version

Comment: Uncaught DiscordjsError Error [DisallowedIntents]: Privileged intent provided is not enabled or whitelisted.
    at createShards (c:\Users\mudit\Desktop\react js\my-app\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:250:15)
No debugger available, can not send 'variables'

Comment: new error is coming

Comment: @MuditDagar I wrote in my answer to double check your [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers) and enable any intents on that page. If you copied the exact same code in my answer, the error shouldn't occur, because I have tested it myself. Open your `package.json` and give me the exact version of Discord.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250572/discussion-between-node-modules-and-mudit-dagar).